# Отсутствует интернет на пользователе Ubutnu 18 на VPS сервере. Как решить проблему?

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, debian

Под root интернет есть. При создании пользователя, на нем интернет отсутствует. Ubuntu 18 - VPS сервер. Как решить проблему? Может конфигу проморгал...

Comment: Нагуглил с богом
От рута
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner <имя пользователя> -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 2):

Нагуглил, надо от рута:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner <имя пользователя> -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Отформатируйте команду